# How to run %run command inside if condition

Tags: azure-databricks

I want to run the %run only when if condition is satisfied

I have tried this:

a=0
if a==0:
%run "path"

it is not working, I want to run the %run only when if condition is satisfied I am getting error notebook path not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dbutils.notebook.run`

code:

```py
a=0 
if a==0:
    print(dbutils.notebook.run("/Workspace/Users/xx@yy.com/sql_res",90))
```

Output:

[image]